# Given an array of 0 and 1, find minimum no. of swaps to bring all 1s together (only adjacent swaps allowed)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

If given an array of 1's and 0's, what's good algorithm to show the minimum number of adjacent swaps needed to group all of the 1's together. The 1's don't need to be grouped at any specific place in the array. They just need to be grouped in whatever place provides for the minimum number of adjacent swaps.

For example, if the array looks like this...

`1,0,0,1,1,0,1`

...the minimum number of adjacent swaps would be 3, because you'd center on index 4 and do the following swaps:

1. Swap indices 0 and 1, resulting in:
   `0,1,0,1,1,0,1`
2. Swap indices 1 and 2, resulting in:
   `0,0,1,1,1,0,1`
3. Swap indices 5 and 6, resulting in:
   `0,0,1,1,1,1,0`

Anyone have a good algorithm for finding the minimum number of adjacent swaps for any array of 1's and 0's?

Comment: This is actually a bit interesting. I was thinking you were merely sorting, but you're goal is to group all the 1's regardless of index position. Hmmm.

Comment: The question title states minimum number of swaps (not partial shifts), which in the example would be 2 (swap index 0,2 | swap index 5,6). Perhaps you meant adjacent swaps?

Comment: @rcgldr, yeah, looking at the example, though, I think the OP is asking for adjacent swaps.

Comment: @JonathanM what if input is 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 , to get that one zero out we would need 3 adjacent swaps

Comment: @RandomGuy, yeah, I did a similar example just now. My initial thought about counting zeroes was clearly wrong.

Comment: The answer is going to involve finding a "population center" to group the 1's to, then doing the calculation to determine the number of steps required for the grouping. Very interesting.

Comment: @kutta, just curious: what is the application for this? It's a nice little puzzle without application, but it would be even cooler if there's an application.

Comment: Seems kinda homeworky.

Comment: This question might be more on topic over at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com. I would be curious to see the solutions presented there.

Comment: @DavidVogel, it doesn't seem to fit codegolf, which is described as: Code-golf is a competition to solve a particular problem in the fewest bytes of source code.

Comment: Close voters: while the question is not asked well, it's neither unclear what the OP is asking nor too broad. Please reconsider.

Comment: @JonathanM I downvoted because the OP showed no effort to solve the problem himself.

Comment: @PatriceGahide, me too initially. I'm asking about close votes, not down votes.

Comment: @JonathanM Sorry, didn't pay enough attention ;)

Answer (score 8):

UPDATED:

The algorithm determines center by just getting an array of all indices of 1's. The center of that array will always hold the center index. Much faster.

```
oneIndices = array of indices of all 1's in the input
middleOfOnesIndices = round(oneIndices.length/2)-1    // index to the center index
minimumSwaps = 0
foreach index i of oneIndices
    minimumSwaps += aboluteValue(oneIndices[middleOfOneIndices]-oneIndices[i])-absoluteValue(middleOfOneIndices-i);
```

Here's a fiddle to see it in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/3pmwrk0d/6/

This was a fun one. Thanks for the question.

Comment: There must be a O(n) solution, I'll check my algorithm later and post it.

Comment: It was definitely no so obvious to see that a convenient center would be so easy to compute. Then the number of swaps for each 1 is just the distance to that center, minus the number of 1's between them. Very nice.

Comment: Very nice algorithm. What's the mathematical theorem behind the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, firstly I would like to suggest that the minimum number of adjacent swaps would be 2 for your given example instead of 3. As just swap index 0 with index 2. So 1 swap from left and 1 swap from right.**

Here is my way to find minimum of swaps to bring the array in consecutive 1's form -

Step 1 : First find the centre index for maximum number of consecutive 1's
Step 2 : Parse the left side of array to swap it and count the number of swap in a efficient manner(Do not swap unnecessarily)
Step 3 : Do the same for the right side array
Step 4 : Plus the counts of both side.

Please have a look at my java program based on same strategy :

```
`public class MinimumSwap 
{
//function to find consecutive number index
public static int[] getMaxConsecutiveIndex(List<Integer> array)
{
    int desiredIndex = -1;
    int count = 0;
    int dupDesiredIndex = -1;
    int dupCount = 0;

    int i = 0;
    while(i < array.size())
    {
        if(array.get(i) == 0)
        {
            //pass duplcateIndex value to desiredIndex if count is more
            if(dupCount > count)
            {
                desiredIndex = dupDesiredIndex;
                count = dupCount;
            }
            dupDesiredIndex = -1;
            dupCount = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            if(dupDesiredIndex == -1) 
            {
                dupDesiredIndex = i;
                dupCount = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                dupCount++;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return new int[]{desiredIndex,count};
}

public static int swapCount(List<Integer> array,int startIndex, int      endIndex, boolean side)
{
    // side == false means 0 at the left
    // side == true means 1 at the left
    System.out.println("startIndex  "+startIndex+"  endIndex  "+endIndex+" side "+side);
    int swapCount = 0; 
    if(side == false)
    {
        while(startIndex <= endIndex)
        {
            if(array.get(endIndex) == 0) // swap from the end only if it is 0
            {
                //check for first 1 from left to swap
                while(array.get(startIndex) == 0 && (startIndex != endIndex))
                    startIndex++;

                if(array.get(startIndex) == 1)  
                {
                    // now swap
                    int temp = array.get(startIndex);
                    array.set(startIndex, array.get(endIndex));
                    array.set(endIndex,temp);
                    swapCount++;
                    endIndex--;
                }
            }
            endIndex--;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while(startIndex <= endIndex)
        {
            if(array.get(startIndex) == 0) // swap from the starting only if it is 0
            {
                //check for first 1 from right to swap
                while(array.get(endIndex) == 0 && (startIndex != endIndex))
                    endIndex--;
                if(array.get(endIndex) == 1)    
                {
                    // now swap
                    int temp = array.get(startIndex);
                    array.set(startIndex, array.get(endIndex));
                    array.set(endIndex,temp);
                    swapCount++;
                    startIndex++;
                }
            }
            startIndex++;
        }
    }
    return swapCount;
}

public static void main(String...strings)
{
    List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int temp[] = {0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1};
    //int temp[] = {1,0,0,1,1,0,1};
    for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++)
        arr.add(temp[i]);


    int centerIndex = getMaxConsecutiveIndex(arr)[0];
    int consequtivecount = getMaxConsecutiveIndex(arr)[1];
    System.out.println("centerIndex "+centerIndex+"  consequtivecount "+consequtivecount);
    int swapCountLeft = swapCount(arr,0, centerIndex-1, false);
    int swapCountRight = swapCount(arr,centerIndex+consequtivecount, arr.size()-1, true);
    System.out.println("total swap count "+swapCountLeft+" :: "+swapCountRight);
    System.out.println("array after swapping "+arr);
}
```

}
`

I am not very sure about performance. But as per my knowledge it should not be inefficient. If anyone finds any performance issue please do let me know :)

Comment: Please re-read the post. He's asking for the minimum number of *adjacent* swaps.

Comment: Yes, you are right he's asking for adjacent swaps.I didn't get the question correctly. In that case the second function of swapping needs to be change to count minimum number of adjacent swap both the side. Let me changes that function and re-post.

Comment: Please Can You edit your post to reflect the comment?

Answer (score 0):

**Approach :** 
This can be done by finding number of zeroes to the right side of every 1 and add them. In order to sort the array every one always has to perform a swap operation with every zero on its right side.

So the **total number of swap operations for a particular 1 in array is the number of zeroes on its right hand side**. Find the number of zeroes on right side for every one i.e. the number of swaps and add them all to obtain the total number of swaps.

// Java code to find minimum number of swaps to sort a binary array

```java
class MinimumNumberOfSwapsNeeded { 

    static int findMinSwaps(int arr[], int n) 
    { 
        // Array to store count of zeroes 
        int noOfZeroes[] = new int[n]; 
        int i, count = 0; 

        // Count number of zeroes 
        // on right side of every one. 
        noOfZeroes[n - 1] = 1 - arr[n - 1]; 
        for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--)  
        { 
            noOfZeroes[i] = noOfZeroes[i + 1]; 
            if (arr[i] == 0) 
                noOfZeroes[i]++; 
        } 

        // Count total number of swaps by adding number 
        // of zeroes on right side of every one. 
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)  
        { 
            if (arr[i] == 1) 
                count += noOfZeroes[i]; 
        } 
        return count; 
    }       
    // Driver Code 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        int ar[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 }; 
        System.out.println(findMinSwaps(ar, ar.length)); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**
Grouping the array of 0's and 1's such that minimum swaps can be calculated in O(2*n) ~ O(n) complexity.**

```
package com.segregate.array;    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArraySegregation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        /*
         * 
         * List -> low high [1 1 0 0 1 0] -> [ 000111] or [111000]
         * 
         * 1 1 0 0 1 0 -> 000111
         */
        arr.add(0);
        arr.add(0);
        arr.add(0);
        arr.add(1);
        arr.add(1);
        arr.add(0);
        arr.add(1);
        arr.add(0);
        arr.add(0);
        List<Integer> arr1 = new ArrayList<>(arr);

        int low = 0, high = arr.size() - 1;
        int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0;
        // case for swaps such that all 0 in the left side.
        while (low < high) {
            switch (arr.get(low)) {
            case 0:
                while (arr.get(low) == 0)
                    low++;
                break;
            case 1:
                while (arr.get(high) == 1)
                    high--;
                swap(low, high, arr);
                counter1++;
                high--;
                low++;
                break;
            }

        }
        // case for swaps such that all 0 in the right side.
        /*
         * [1 1 0 0 1 0] -> 11 1 0 0 0
         * 
         * 
         */
        low=0;high = arr1.size() - 1;
        while (low < high) {
            switch (arr1.get(low)) {
            case 0:
                while (arr1.get(high) == 0)
                    high--;
                swap(low, high, arr1);
                counter2++;
                high--;
                low++;
                break;
            case 1:
                while (arr1.get(low) == 1)
                    low++;
                break;
            }

        }
        
        int count = (counter1 > counter2) ? counter2 : counter1;
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    private static void swap(int low, int high, List<Integer> arr) {
        int temp1 = 0;
        temp1 = arr.get(low);// 1
        arr.remove(low);
        arr.add(low, arr.get(high-1));
        arr.remove(high-1);
        arr.add(high, temp1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple, but not very clever algorithm that will perform an exhaustive search for any input in the range [0, 255].

- **Input:**

  - binary string
- **Output:**

  - optimal number of steps
  - number of optimal solutions
  - one detailed example

```js
var transition = [],
    isSolution = [];

function init() {
  var msk = [ 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, 192 ],
      i, j, n, x, cnt, lsb, msb, sz = [];

  for(i = 0; i < 0x100; i++) {
    for(n = cnt = msb = 0, lsb = 8; n < 8; n++) {
      if(i & (1 << n)) {
        cnt++;
        lsb = Math.min(lsb, n);
        msb = Math.max(msb, n);
      }
    }
    sz[i] = msb - lsb;
    isSolution[i] = (sz[i] == cnt - 1);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < 0x100; i++) {
    for(j = 0, transition[i] = []; j < 0x100; j++) {
      x = i ^ j;
      if(msk.indexOf(x) != -1 && (x & i) != x && (x & j) != x && sz[j] <= sz[i]) {
        transition[i].push(j);
      }
    }
  }
}

function solve() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('bin').value, 2),
      path = [ x ],
      list = [],
      i, min, sol = [], res = [];

  recurse(x, path, list);

  for(i in list) {
    if(min === undefined || list[i].length <= min) {
      min = list[i].length;
      (sol[min] = (sol[min] || [])).push(list[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log('Optimal length: ' + (min - 1) + ' step(s)');
  console.log('Number of optimal solutions: ' + sol[min].length);
  console.log('Example:');

  for(i in sol[min][0]) {
    res.push(('0000000' + sol[min][0][i].toString(2)).substr(-8, 8));
  }
  console.log(res.join(' -> '));
}

function recurse(x, path, list) {
  if(isSolution[x]) {
    list.push(path);
    return;
  }
  for(i in transition[x]) {
    if(path.indexOf(y = transition[x][i]) == -1) {
      recurse(y, path.slice().concat(y), list);
    }
  }
}

init();
```

```html
<input id="bin" maxlength="8" placeholder="enter binary string">
<button onclick="solve()">solve</button>
```