# Find minimum no of swaps required to move all 1's together in a binary array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Eg: Array : [0,1,0,1,1,0,0]

Final Array: [0,0,1,1,1,0,0] , So swaps required = 1

i need a O(n) or O(nlogn) solution

Comment: Interesting problem, but Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.  We are here to _help_ you with your problem, but not to solve it completely outright.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Yeah i know , I just need an approach

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have used O(n^2) solution

Comment: Question: Does the island of 1's have to be in a specific place in the array, or could it be anywhere?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It could be any where

Comment: Merge sort, or any other divide and conquer sorting algorithm, can solve this `O(n*lgn)` time.  Ensuring that it was done with a minimal number of swaps is another story though.

Comment: Explain your approach (even though it is quadratic). On Stack Overflow, you get tend to get much better response to homework type questions when you show what you have already done.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38748760/56778

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in `O(n)`:

In one pass through the data, determine the number of 1s. Call this `k` (it is just the sum of the elements in the list).

In a second pass through the data, use a sliding window of width `k` to find the number, `m` which is the maximum number of 1s in any window of size `k`. Since this is homework, I'll leave the details to you, but it can be done in `O(n)`.

Then: the minimal number of swaps is `k-m`.

Comment: Great answer..!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** This answer assumes that only two neighboring cells can be swapped. If the distance between the two swapped elements is arbitrary, see @JohnColeman's answer.

---

This can be done easily in linear time.

Suppose that the array is called `a` and its size is `n`.

1. Allocate integer array `b` of size `n`. Walk from left to right, save in b[i] the number of ones seen so far in `a[0], ..., a[i]`.
2. Allocate integer array `c` of size `n`. Walk from right to left, save in c[i] the number of ones seen so far in `a[i], ..., a[N - 1]`.
3. Initialize integer `res = 0`. Walk through `a` one last time. For each `i` with `a[i] = 0`, add `res += min(b[i] c[i])`
4. Output `res`

Why this works? Each zero must somehow bubble out of the block of ones. So, every zero must either "bubble-up" past all ones to the right of it, or it must "bubble-down" past all ones to the left of it. Swapping zeros with zeros is waste of time, therefore the process of zero-eviction from the homogeneous block of ones must start with those zeros that are as close to the first `1` or the last `1` as possible. This means, that every zero will have to make exactly `min(b[i], c[i])` swaps with `1`s to exit the homogeneous block of ones.

Example:

```
a = [0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
b = [0,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]
c = [6,6,5,5,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,0]
```

now, `min(b,c)` would be (no need to compute it explicitly):

```
m = [0,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,2,1,1,0]
     ^   ^     ^   ^   ^   ^
```

The interesting values of `min(b[i], c[i])` which correspond to `0`s are marked with `^`. Summing it up yields: `0 + 1 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0 = 7`.

Indeed:

```
    [0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
    [0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0] 1
    [0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0] 2 = 1 + 1
    [0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0] 3
    [0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0] 4 = 1 + 1 + 2
    [0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0] 5
    [0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0] 6
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0] 7 = 1 + 1 + 2 + 3

done: block of ones homogeneous.
```

Runtime for computation of the number `res` of swaps is obviously `O(n)`. (Note: it does NOT say that the number of swaps is itself `O(n)`).

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider each 1 as a potential static point. Then the cost for the left side of the static point would be the number of 1's to the left subtracted by the number of 1's already in the section it would naturally extend to, the length of which is the number of 1's on the left. Similarly for the right side.

Now find a way to do it efficiently for each potential static 1 :) Hint: think about how we could update those values as we iterate across the array.

```
1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
          x potential static point
    <----- would extend to
           -----> would extend to

left cost at x: 3 - 2 = 1
right cost at x: 3 - 1 = 2
```