# Minimum number of adjacent swaps of binary array

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a binary array, find the number of minimum adjacent swaps needed to group 1's and 0's.

**Example:**

```
Input : 0,1,0,1 (array with 0 based index)
Swaps needed : 0,1,0,1 -> 0,0,1,1 (1 swap from index 1 to index 2)

Solution : 1
```

**Exmaple:**

```
Input : 1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1
Swaps needed : 
1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1 -> 1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1 -> 1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0 -> 1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0 -> 1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0 -> 1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0 -> 1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0

Total 6 swaps so the solution is 6.
```

The 1's and 0's can be positioned at the beginning or end but they should be at a single place i.e. either begin or end.

I have come up with below logic for this requirement. I tried this in a hackerrank, it failed for a single hidden test case and gave timeout for 3 test cases as I have nested loops in my code.

```
static int countSwaps(List<Integer> list) {
    int temp;
    int swaps = 0;
    int n = list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if ((list.get(j) == 0) && (list.get(j + 1) == 1)) {
                temp = list.get(j);
                list.set(j, list.get(j + 1));
                list.set(j + 1, temp);
                swaps++;
            }
        }
    }

    return swaps;
}
```

What is a better approach to solving this program?

I have already gone through this post [Given an array of 0 and 1, find minimum no. of swaps to bring all 1s together (only adjacent swaps allowed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748760/given-an-array-of-0-and-1-find-minimum-no-of-swaps-to-bring-all-1s-together-o) but the answers are not giving correct output.

Comment: The reason it's timing out is because you're actually doing the swap operations manually, which is O(n^2). There's a mathematical way to count the number of swaps without actually performing the operation. Unfortunately, off the top of my head I don't know the function, but [this solves it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-swaps-required-sort-binary-array/). Instead of a O(n^2), this is an O(2n) -> O(n).

Comment: @Compass, I see that the link is for `Sort Binary array`, so it always tries to place 0 at first place. But in my case, the first place can be occupied by 0 or 1

Comment: There's a way to determine which way to sort, but you could also do both sorts at O(4n) -> O(n) and take the lower value as well until you figure out that formula. Pretty sure it's just counting which side has more #s to move.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Building on [answer by Gene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56879081/5221149), fixing the compile error and supporting moving 1's to the left (to the beginning) *or* moving them to the right (to the end), aka moving 0's to the left:

```
static int countSwaps(int... a) {
    int n0 = 0, i0 = 0, n1 = 0, i1 = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < a.length; ++p) {
        if (a[p] == 0)
            n0 += p - i0++; // No. of steps to move the 0 to the left
        else
            n1 += p - i1++; // No. of steps to move the 1 to the left
    }
    return Math.min(n0, n1); // Choose lowest no. of steps
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(countSwaps(0,1,0,1));
System.out.println(countSwaps(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1));
System.out.println(countSwaps(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1));
```

*Output*

```
1
6
6
```

Answer (score 7):

To move all 1's to the left, let p(i) be the position of i'th 1 from left to right. It ultimately needs to move to position i. This will need p(i) - i swaps.  Just sum up this quantity for all i.

```
int countSwaps(int [] a) {
  int n = 0, i = 0;
  for (int p = 0; p < a.length; ++p)
    if (a[p] == 1) {
      n += p - i;
      ++i;
    }
  return n;
}
```

Moving to the right is symmetric. Do a similar computation and take the min.

Comment: Thanks, I am not able to understand the explanation provided, can you please explain how this logic works?

Comment: That is great, except it doesn't compile.

Comment: That is great, but only half the challenge. *"The 1's and 0's can be positioned at the **beginning or end**"* E.g. input `1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1` returns 6, but input `1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1` returns **9**, while the real answer is also 6, since you just move the 1's right instead of left for a valid result.

Comment: @Gene, Based on my understanding, this logic is placing `1's` at the beginning all the time, but in my case they can be kept at the end also.

Comment: @learner Sorry I missed the bit about beginning or end. Same idea applies. Just compute both and take the min as Andreas has.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution (Java):

```
public static int minSwaps(int[] arr) {
    int min_swaps1 = 0;
    int zero_counts = 0;
    int min_swaps2 = 0;
    int one_counts = 0;

    for (int j : arr) {
        if (j == 0) {
            zero_counts++;
            min_swaps2 += one_counts;
        } else {
            one_counts++;
            min_swaps1 += zero_counts;
        }
    }

    return Math.min(min_swaps1, min_swaps2);
}
```

Comment: The question is about Java, not Python.